# can't get value out of array

Tags: php, arrays

Why isn't this working?

```
print_r($photo);
echo $photo['type'];
```

this is outputting:

```
Array ( ['type'] => newPhoto ['fileName'] => 133249963433.jpg ) 

Notice: Undefined index: type in /path/to/Logic.php on line 153
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /path/to/Logic.php on line 154
```

This has to be so simple though..?

## edit:

FOUND THE SOLUTION, but i can't post it as solution, because i don't have enough reputation points.

The array was generated from a form with php generated hidden inputs. I named those inputs like this:

```
name="photos['.$uniqid.'][\'type\']" value="exisitingPhoto">
name="photos['.$uniqid.'][\'fileName\']" value="'.$photoTag['photoName'].'">`
```

It has to be this:

```
name="photos['.$uniqid.'][type]" value="exisitingPhoto">
name="photos['.$uniqid.'][fileName]" value="'.$photoTag['photoName'].'">`
```

So, the backslashes and ' ' are not allowed in this.

Thank you all for the help!

Comment: Double-check whether this is line 154. I don't think it is.

Comment: @Royw It doesn't look like there is any issue; I just ran the code...

Comment: Try `echo $photo[0]['type']`. sometimes it works.

Comment: It certainly is line 153 (not 154 ;-)  )

Comment: Still not working with $photo[0]['type'] :S

Comment: paste the code which is written before print_r($photo);

Comment: I found the solution, but can't post it as solution because i don't have enough reputation points. I'll edit my original post, with the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Just for debugging purposes please try

```
$key = 'type';
print_r($photo);
if ( isset($photo[$key]) ) {
    echo $photo[$key];
}
else {
    echo __FILE__, ':', __LINE__, ' $photo[$key] not set', "<br />\n";
}
```